# "Incorrect syntax near '='" error when saving database connection settings during phpBB installation

Tags: sql-server, windows, phpbb

I'm trying to install phpBB, and all I need is a working SQL database w/ login etc. I have tried using mySQL and it wouldn't let me change the password (I guess this is a common issue) so now I'm trying MS SQL and even it's not working. Here is the phpBB login:
[image]

My username / password are below that. When I press 'Next Step' it gives me that error. I have Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express installed, and when I run the SQL Server Configuration Manager, I set the Logon as: Local System (so I set my username/password to my servers login. Let me know if this is incorrect). Regardless, it should still connect and I'm curious to why it won't. I'm new to this somewhat, but I don't see a tool installed to edit/add databases, just the service itself. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default SQL express accepts only shared-memory connections. (generally supported by other MSFT products and only works on the local machine) phpBB for obvious reasons connects via TCP/IP. To use it with SQL express you'll need to enable TCP/IP connectivity. Don't bother with Named Pipes, that's not needed. To enable TCP, follow these instructions:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx

Edit: ADD

Additionally you'll need to create a SQL account for phBB to use. Follow this guide to create an account:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx

and then grant the account access. The easiest way to test it out would be to grant your new user DBO access to the DB in question. Ratchet it down as needed after that. (if you care)

Note you may need to enable SQL auth as outlined in the first post here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/Vsexpressinstall/thread/aaf2f68c-4a40-44c8-b7ee-b2f5d94e23c3

Comment: Thanks for the response! For whatever reason, my TCP/IP was already enabled. I enabled the Browser and still no cigar.. I'm not sure what to put for the database name, I think I need to create one? Anything else you recommend? I'm gonna try to download Server Management Studio and create a blank database

Comment: @Zakman411 Ahh! I think your issue is with the login. You need to create a SQL account, not use your username/password as that will not have inherent access. I doubt phBB will support native windows auth so I'll update my answer to include instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try a database name with no spaces.  This is not asking for what kind of database you have.  Each sql server instance can play host to multiple databases, and so it needs to know the name of the particular database within your sql server installation it should use.  It's also unclear to me whether it wants to create this database or expects it to already exist.  If it's looking for an existing database, you may need to use Sql Server Management Studio (or similar tool) to create it.

Try localhost\SQLEXPRESS or \SQLEXPRESS for the server hostname or DSN.  Sql Server can install multiple instances to the same machine, and uses this convention to distinguish which instance you need.  Express Edition often installs using the \SQLEXPRESS named instance by default.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I downloaded SQL Server Management Studio, created a new DB called 'Default'. I put that as my Database Name, my windows login + password, and am trying your suggestions for the Server Hostname or DSN. No cigar. What else could possibly be going wrong this is very frustrating?

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck [populating your config.php file manually](http://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/rebuilding-your-configphp-file/).

That error smells like a SQL injection vulnerability.  Does your username and/or password have quotes, spaces, special characters - basically anything non-alphanumeric?

You might also find these form threads to be useful (or at least entertaining):

- [Does phpbb3 work with SQLServer 2008?](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1167325) (look about halfway down the page)
- [Installation problem](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1019915&start=0)